# Load page before content (data from database)

Tags: asp.net, linq, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am creating my first Blazor web application for self education purposes. There is a simple database with data. Dataset is currently rather small. However while clicking on page link it takes some 1-2 seconds to load. Just wondering that how long it would take if dataset would consist of larger amount of items. Is there a way to load page first and then populate the data?

**public class EmployeesBase : ComponentBase:**

```
[Inject]
protected IRepository Repository { get; set; }
protected List<BlazorCompanyManager.Data.Employee> employees;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  this.employees = this.Repository.GetEmployees();
}
```

**public interface IRepository:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorCompanyManager.Data
{
  public interface IRepository
  {
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees();

    public Employee GetEmployee(Guid id);

    public bool UpdateEmployee(Employee employee);

    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee);

    public void DeleteEmployee(Guid id);
  }
}
```

**public class Repository : IRepository:**

```
protected readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
  this.dbContext = db;
}

public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  return this.dbContext.EmployeeTable.ToList();
}
```

I have tried to make it work with `OnInitializedAsync` and other override methods, but got no success so far. Could anyone give some idea on how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You''re running an async code block synchronously, thus blocking the UI thread.

```
this.dbContext.EmployeeTable.ToList()
```

should look like this:

```
public async ValueTask<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
{
    using var dbContext = this.DBContext.CreateDbContext();
    var list = await dbContext
    .EmployeeeTable
    .ToListAsync() 
    ?? new List<TRecord>();
    return list;
}
```

To do this you also need to move to an `IDbContextFactory` in your Repository.  You can no longer rely on a single DbContext.

```
protected virtual IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> DBContext { get; set; } = null;

public xxxxxRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbContext)
    => this.DBContext = dbContext;
```

Startup/Program

```
var dbContext = configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:DBContext");
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbContext), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

You component initialization then looks like this.

```
protected async override void OnInitializedAsyc()
{
  this.employees = await this.Repository.GetEmployeesAsync();
}
```

Data loading will be dependant on your data server, but the UI will be responsive.  You may need to consider paging as the data set grows - you can only display so many rows at once so why fetch them all at once!

Comment: Seems like this is the way how to do it in Net Core 5. Also found this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-7/

Comment: I think I have done all correct, but I am getting exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' 
This is dropping on employees List. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I got it... need to add this.employees = new List<Employee>(); to constructor. Thank you sir! I will update my repo. There are some typos in your answer, but they are easy to fix!

Comment: Can you check my repo? Is it now as it should be?

Comment: @HiFo -  Fix the typos in my answer if you wish.   I can't see a link to your repo.  Am I being blind?  On a more general note on building Blazor data driven apps I have a repo that demos a Clean Design approach - you can see it [here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo)  which should give you some ideas about how to build your app.

Comment: Can you add database to your clean architecture example to understand how it should be implemented?

Comment: @HiFo -  NP - A question first -  Do you know how to set up Entity Framework for your Database?  IOW - Can I assume you have EF set up and we can link a Data Broker into your EF?  Also you can see a more complete (complex) example of how to build a Blazor Database Application here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.Database.  There's a repo, a working site on Azure and a detailed set of articles showing you how it works.